# Resize image before upload using ng2-file-upload

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, ng2-file-upload

How can I resize image before upload when using [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload)?

In pure JavaScript I'd load image to Canvas, then resize. Does `ng2-file-upload` have hany events allowing to pre-process uploades files? Any example?

Answer (score 1):

You have the possibility to use `onAfterAddingFile`.

```
fileUploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({....})
```

and the `onAfterAddingFile` will fire when you add a file:

```
this.fileUploader.onAfterAddingFile = () => {
   console.log(this.fileUploader.queue)
   // do stuff
};
```

Comment: So we got a FileItem then what ? 
What is do stuff ?